# Always got error on testnet: Transaction was not mined within750 seconds

Tags: node.js, web3js

```
/** executes contract method by creating transaction
 * @param {string} from - payer address
 * @param {string} to - payee address
 * @param {int} amount - number of tokens
 * @param {string} type - transaction type
 */
web3.eth.getGasPrice().then(gasPrice => {
    gasPrice *= 2;
    gasPrice = Math.floor(gasPrice);
    
    var data = myContract.methods.transfer(receiverAddress).encodeABI();
    var nonceValue = 0;
    web3.eth.getTransactionCount(hostAddress).then(function(res){
        nonceValue = res;
        console.log('nonce' , 'nonce = ' + nonceValue);
    })

    var rawTx = {
        nonce: '0x20',
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(99000),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
        value: '0x00',
        from:hostAddress,
        to:contractAddress,
        data: data,
        chainId: 3
    }

    var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
    tx.sign(hexPrivateKey);

    var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
    console.log("start sendSignedTransaction");
    console.log("serializedTx", serializedTx.toString('hex'));

    var transaction = web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'));
    transaction.on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber, receipt) => {
        console.log('confirmation', confirmationNumber);
        res.render('index', { title:"confirmation" + confirmationNumber});
    });
    transaction.on('transactionHash', hash => {
        console.log('transaction hash', hash);
        res.render('index', { title:"transaction hash" + hash});
    });
    transaction.on('receipt', receipt => {
        console.log('transaction reciept', receipt);
        res.json({ receipt });
        res.render('index', { title:"transaction reciept "+receipt });
    });
    transaction.on('error', error => {
        console.log('transaction error', error);
        res.render('index', { title:console.error });
    });
});
```

**even I rise the gas price, and switched the testnet to ropsten/rinkeby**, the error response always need mo to confirm that the transaction was properly sent.

> Error: Transaction was not mined within750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!

Could someone help me, where I am wrong?